# Can Naruto use Rinnegan techniques if he were to implant it?

Tags: naruto

In the recent episode Naruto mention about releasing Infinite Tsukuyomi to Sasuke. Sasuke replied, "Kakashi can use his eyes to release the jutsu".

Can Naruto use Rinnegan techniques if he were to implant it?

Comment: I edited your question so that the title matches the question in the body. Feel free to change it back if this is not what you meant.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, yes.

Long answer, Nagato (Pain), who was an Uzumaki, was able to use Rinnegan jutsus. Naruto, who is also an Uzumaki, should also be able to use Rinnegan much like Nagato.

Answer (score 0):

Naruto would as he is a descendant of ashura by reincarnate lineage. He is also an uzumaki, a distant blood relative of the senju who were the descendants of ashura, and as such he would have a genetic disposition and high chakra disposition toward the sage of six paths techniques, making the rinnegan easier for him to access and use without massive chakra drain.